# sql server sort by first column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
exec ('select * from variable_table_name
order by @variable')
```

I'm trying to put together a dynamic sql statment where you specify a table name and sort column. It would be nice if I can just specify a table name to make the sql work.

Is there a way to choose the first column of a table to sort by if @variable sort by not specified?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use:

```
ORDER BY 1;
```

From [ORDER BY Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx):

> order_by_expression - Specifies a column or expression on which to sort the query result set. A sort column can be specified as a name or column alias, **or a nonnegative integer representing the position of the column in the select list**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I think I just found it, you can specify an int for the Order By.

Answer (score 1):

This script should do the job

```
DECLARE @tbl NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @tbl = 'MyTbl'
SET @col = '' --enter column name when required

IF @col = ''
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tbl + ' ORDER BY 1'
END
ELSE
    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tbl + ' ORDER BY ' + @col

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Using + in a sql statement to execute really makes God kill a puppy :(

Before you know it someone will use the value:
MyTbl; SELECT * FROM supersecretcreditcardtable

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (Ive used Adventureworks as an example):-

```
DECLARE @SORTCOLUMN varchar(50);

SET @SORTCOLUMN = 'OrganizationLevel';

IF @SORTCOLUMN IS NULL
    EXEC('SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Employee ORDER BY 1')
ELSE
    EXEC('SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Employee ORDER BY ' + @SORTCOLUMN)
```

Leave out the 'SET @SORTCOLUMN' line to default to the first column